# wordpress custom login validation when user is not active

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom login and wanted to check if the user already activated or not.

I also have my custom registration which would send the activation key and when activation key is clicked it automatically changed the user meta value. That is already okay. My issue is when user will login even though it is not yet activated can logged in. It seems that my validation code does not work and I am having trouble why. Here is my code

```
add_action( 'authenticate', 'check_username_password', 1, 3);
function check_username_password( $login, $username, $password ) {
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$user = $username->ID;
$status = get_user_meta($user, 'ja_disable_user', true);

if( !empty( $referrer ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) ) { 
if( $username == "" || $password == "" ){
        if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=empty' )) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('/login/?login=empty') );
            }
            else {
                wp_redirect( $referrer );
            }
    exit;
    }
if($status == 2){ //when meta value is 2 user account is pending
if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=not_activated' )) {
            //wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=empty');
            wp_redirect( home_url('/login/?login=not_activated') );
            }
            else {
                wp_redirect( $referrer );
            }
    exit;

    }   
  }
 }
```